# Running JavaScript Console in Android Chrome (without pc)

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, console.log

Is there any way to open console in Chrome android version to run something like

```
console.log("Hello world!");
```

**WITHOUT PC**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oh I got it.

Open your browser and go to "Add bookmarks".
Paste this code as URL:

```
javascript:(function () { var script = document.createElement('script'); script.src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda"; document.body.appendChild(script); script.onload = function () { eruda.init() } })();
```

Now open a site and go in search bar. You will end up with this.

[image: Image here]

Press the bookmark that you recently created, and you will see a floating button press on that and boom!

Comment: I tried this but in Google Chrome on Android I don't see any "Add Bookmark" function or menu.

Answer (score 1):

javascript:(function () { var script = document.createElement('script'); script.src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda"; document.body.appendChild(script); script.onload = function () { eruda.init() } })();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Duplicate of @user13658312 answer

Answer (score -2):

Chrome android does not provide developer options, there is no way.